# Writing answers - slow rendering + CPU load

Tags: bug, mathjax

This is the same issue like the one presented [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/writing-answers-works-very-slow), only now with a more powerfull machine. The fact that preview is generated instantaneously makes it hard to write longer answers. Sometimes, even my quad-core machine lags... Does anyone else has observed this behavior?

(I had a suggestion in the past of adding a "do not compile as I type" option.)

Comment: My Atom Z2760 is usually able to withstand writing new answers (editing is another story), but today it was quite annoying to write an answer to a question that had a couple of answers already (although none of which were particularly heavy with MathJax).

Comment: I have also noticed this erratic behaviour. Sometimes the preview will just take ages to kick in, and then to finish, while at other times, I can edit veritable MathJax monsters without a hitch.

Comment: I would really love to see `do not compile as I type`  as an option. Sure, it is very helpful for most most people who do not know how to use $\rm\LaTeX$ well, but it is a major annoyance for those of us who are well acquainted, especially when writing a long answer. The edit grace period also makes it an appealing option in my mind.

Comment: I think the last time I just copied what I had written so far to Notepad, continued to work on it and then when it was close enough to finished it I copied it back over to here. But then the delay was even longer.